# Open an OpenCv Project in XCode - Run destination My Mac 64-bit is not valid

Tags: c, xcode, macos, opencv

I downloaded openCV and extracted the project. I navigated into the Samples/FaceTracker folder. Double clicked on the project (`FaceTracker.xcodeproj`), and clicked on the run button when the project was loaded in XCOde. I get the following error, which doesn't allow me to run the application;

> The run destination My Mac 64-bit is not valid for Running the scheme
>   'FaceTracker'.
>
> The scheme 'FaceTracker' contains no buildables that can be built for
>   the SDKs supported by > the run destination My Mac 64-bit. Make sure
>   your targets all specify SDKs that are supported by this version of
>   Xcode.

The file `OpenCv.framework` is missing, but i looked for it and i am unable to find a file with that name. How can i resolve this issue ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1- Your XCode project is not able to find the required library, or it finds one but its not compatible with your current operating system/processor/build settings. The missing framework and the error message suggests this.

2- May be you need to build OpenCV SDK to make sure that it's compatible with your machine, instead of trying to build the example first.

3- Instead of downloading and building openCV, I suggest you use a package management for OS X, like [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/). If you do not need cutting edge `trunk` version, this is a better option, which takes care of all the initial framework setup for you.